# Eigenvalues of matrix product $ADA^T$

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, spectral-radius

I am considering such a matrix product, namely $ADA^T$, where $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix with $n>m$, $D$ is an $m\times m$  positive diagonal matrix. I understand the matrix product is positive semi-definite, but is there an estimation of its largest eigenvalue, saying some relationship with eigenvalues of $D$ or $AA^T$ (or $A^TA$)?

Comment: We have $\lambda_{\max}(ADA^T) \leq \lambda_{\max}(A^TA)\cdot \lambda_{\max}(D)$. Is that a good enough bound?

Comment: Yes, it's desired, but do you have a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\|A\|$ denote the spectral norm (AKA the spectral norm/ the maximum singular value) of $A$. We have $\lambda_{\max}(ADA^T) \leq \lambda_{\max}(A^TA)\cdot \lambda_{\max}(D)$, since
$$
\lambda_{\max}(ADA^T) = \|D^{1/2}A\|^2 \leq (\|D^{1/2}\| \cdot \|A\|)^2 = \|A\|^2 \cdot \|D^{1/2}\|^2 = \lambda_{\max}(A^TA)\cdot \lambda_{\max}(D).
$$

Comment: This is really nice, thanks!

Comment: Are matrices real?

Comment: @lcv Yes, I assume that the matrices have real number entries

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That question was more for the OP. In the affirmative case this answer his/her question and he/she should accept the answer :)